# Spring data lazy load not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I have the two entities similar to the ones below:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate    
public class EntityOne {
    @Id
    public long id;

    public String name;
    public String displayName;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy(value = "name")
    public List<EntityTwo> entityTwoList;
}
```

entity two is

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class EntityTwo {
    @Id
    public long id;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    public EntityOne entityOne;
}
```

service:
`Lists.newArrayList(repository.findAll());`

The service calls the findAll() method of the CRUDRepository. I don't want the list of entity two objects to load when calling findall() but this solution doesn't work. 
Anything incorrect that i am doing here to lazy load the collection. I basically don't want the collection to be loaded until its specified.

By default the mappings are lazy load.

Comment: Jackson is trying to fetch this unfetched object.

Comment: @surya Yeah, it's the JsonManagedReference annotation that makes Spring load everything

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming jackson is trying to load your child objects.

Try followjackson-datatype-hibernate4:2.4.4
Add jackson-datatype-hibernate4:2.4.4 to your dependency and define following bean

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder configureObjectMapper() {
return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
    .modulesToInstall(Hibernate4Module.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about jackson but according to jpa specs you can not force LAZY loading neither can you rely upon it ... you just provide the lazy load hint and it's totally up to the provider to load it lazily or not (unlike EAGER , it forces loading)

Answer (score 0):

First try this,i think you need to specify fetch type lazy or Eager

```
   ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: @surya ManyToOne by default is EAGER! And OneToMany is LAZY readTheDocs

Comment: You are right , I may have misread the answer here , actually I meant for onetomany, where default is lazy.anyway I think this solution won’t work. Because in the question, user said he is trying to load the object and doesn’t want to load the collections Bd it’s not the other way.